# Deploying with mfp push to Azure VM very often fails with error FWLSE3000E

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-cli

I am using MobileFirst 7.1 CLI (mfp push) to build and deploy to remote Azure VM MobileFirst Development Server.

Very often I get FWLSE3000E error, but SOMETIMES deployment succeeds. Firewall is disabled and no ports restrictions are set. How can I resolve this issue?

Complete error:

> Failed to deploy [...wlapp]. Reason: failed to push application: FWLSE3000E: A server error was detected. : invalid entry CRC (expected 0x992b0d60 but got 0x275afea3): HTTP 500 - Internal Server Error.

Comment: Try running with the `-d` flag as well as look at the messages.log file of the server.

Comment: invalid entry CRC is a sign of a corrupted zip archive (.wlapp). This can happen when the connection between your laptop and the VM slow. How big is the .wlapp file?

Comment: There are three apps. Apps sizes are: 23 MB, 23 MB, 55 MB.
messages.log contains:
`java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid distance too far back`
and
`java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry size (expected 423620 but got 423626 bytes)`

Answer (score 0):

Finally we pulled source code on that Azure machine and deployed locally. The main cause was bad internet connection to Azure. Pretty often even remote desktop connection failed.